Can Ubuntu 24.04 be compromised?

I've been using Ubuntu 24.04 for a few months. Since last month I can see a row of unknown letters that automatically appear on my screen when I boot the OS. I can still log in to Ubuntu, but when I shut down my system the same text string appears on my screen.

^@ is the caret notation for a null character. Something seems to be printing \0 characters on the terminal. If you search for "null characters boot", you'll find a couple of things, like this question, for example.

If you get hacked for real, you probably won't notice if you don't know what you're doing. What good is it for someone to print random characters to your screen? They'd rather steal your data / mine crypto, and not have you know about it.

Okay i tried getting into "var/log/" directory and got a few files and well as with the same name "dmesg" and there are a couple of them don't really know which one to remove. Here, at the top i also updated my question and added the screenshot there please do let me know with reference to that it would be really helpful :))

/var/log/dmesg is a log file; it contains info about kernel operations and messages since the last boot. It is not meant to be removed, and it will be created each reboot.

That is likely a driver or hardware problem.
Those characters are not from someone hacking. If that happens you will not notice is on your screen... you see that in access logs from your router.
A thing to do is to remove any 3rd party video drivers. Also check /var/log/, journalctl, and dmesg for errors or notifications (the @^@^@^@^@^@^  is likely in one of those).
You can try a boot repair though that normally only is needed when boot does not work.

Can Ubuntu 24.0LTS be compromised?

Yes, but up to today it requires the assistance of the admin where you need to install software you would not need as a desktop user or where the software is from dubious sources, compromised, and you install it. What can happen in Windows is something Linux solved decades ago: to do anything nasty you need the admin password.
Hacking into a desktop from the internet is, with a vanilla Ubuntu, basically impossible. And that is also the case with software from official repositories. Only issue there is compromised software from repositories: the last time we had a serious problem was the OpenSSL hack.

"If that happens you will not notice is on your screen" -> "If that happens you will not notice it on your screen"
